# android / java se SimpleDateFormat TimeZone issue

Tags: android, date, timezone

I'm encountering a strange issue in a program running on android 2.1 which seems like a bug in android to me. Please enlighten me as to what is going here, as I'm lost. :)

The following program:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

class TestMe {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            String time = "2010-08-01T18:00:00+0000";

            TimeZone tg = TimeZone.getDefault();
            System.out.println(tg.getID());

            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");

            try {
                Date indate = formatter.parse(time);

                String outdate = formatter.format(indate);
                System.out.println(outdate);

                formatter.setTimeZone( TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

                String ooutdate = formatter.format(indate);
                    System.out.println(ooutdate);

                formatter.setTimeZone( TimeZone.getDefault() );
                Date ioutdate = formatter.parse(ooutdate);
                System.out.println(formatter.format(ioutdate));

                } catch( Exception e ) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        }
```

returns this, when using latest java se on the mac:

```
(~) % javac -g TestMe.java && java TestMe                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Europe/Berlin
2010-08-01T20:00:00+0200
2010-08-01T18:00:00+0000
2010-08-01T20:00:00+0200
```

but returns the following when I run it inside a method in my android app on 2.1 :

```
I/System.out( 5379): ------------------------------------------------------------------
I/System.out( 5379): Europe/Berlin
I/System.out( 5379): 2010-08-01T20:00:00+0200
I/System.out( 5379): 2010-08-01T18:00:00+0100
I/System.out( 5379): 2010-08-01T18:00:00+0100
I/System.out( 5379): ------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is anybody aware of problems in this specific android api revision with TimeZone and Date parsing? This is a very strange issue to me, as it the android version should return exactly the same as the java se version but doesn't.

Thanks for any hints,

Karsten

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `setTimeZone("UTC")` with `setTimeZone("GMT")` it might be different implementations as now 0-meridian in BST(British summer time) tz which is GMT+1.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! I tried but unfortunately with the same result as before :/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I tried it and got the same result as you did. I guess its a bug then.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8258 might help you out

Answer (score 0):

I have tested in windows java and android2.3. I am getting the same result in both of the case. I think the bug is no more in android 2.3. Anyway
please check the import statements for android versus that of java

### import statements in android

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
```

### import statements in java

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;
```

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: yes, I'm using these import statements. thanks for responding!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the intended date conversion done using the Calendar object:

```
        try{ 
        String time = "2010-08-01T18:00:00+0000";

        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
        Date indate = formatter.parse(time);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        System.out.println("time right now: " + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" + (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "-" + cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "T" + cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":" + cal.get(Calendar.SECOND) + "Z");

        cal.setTime( indate );

        System.out.println("time from date string: " + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" + (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "-" + cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "T" + cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":" + cal.get(Calendar.SECOND) + "Z");

        Calendar utcCal = new GregorianCalendar( TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        utcCal.setTimeInMillis( cal.getTimeInMillis() );

        System.out.println("time from date string in utc: " + utcCal.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" + (utcCal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "-" + utcCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "T" + utcCal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + utcCal.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":" + utcCal.get(Calendar.SECOND) + "Z");

    } catch( Exception e) {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try recreating your SimpleDateFormat object before each setTimeZone() / format() call.

This fixed an issue I was having when using a common SimpleDateFormat object to format a set of times that spanned a DST change. If the first time in the set was after the DST threshold, all times in the set were formatted correctly. If the first time in the set was before the DST threshold, then all times after the DST threshold were incorrectly formatted (i.e. were one hour out) - and this continued even when I tried calling setTimeZone() before every format() call.

What I inferred from this is that the time zone used by the SimpleDateFormat object is tied to the first format() call, and subsequent calls to setTimeZone() are effectively ignored or overwritten (which sounds to me like a Java issue, rather than an Android issue).